# General properties of integral operators

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-operators

I study integral operators and I have several questions for which I didn't find answers.
I'm looking for references in the first place, books, where this questions discussed.
Here are the questions:

1. **When kernel determines an operator?**
   It's well known, that for any measure space $(X,\mu)$ and $k\in L^2(X\times X)$ operator $$K:L^2(X)\rightarrow L^2(X)\ \ \ \ \ (Kf)(x)=\int\limits_X k(x,y) f(y)\mu(dy)$$
   is well-defined, compact and $\|K\|\le \|k\|_{L^2}$. My question is: are there more general statements on when some function $k(x,y)$ defines such an operator in $L^2$?
2. **When integral operator is self-adjoint?** It's clear that if $k(x,y)=\overline{k(y,x)}$, thet $K$ is self-adjoint. Is the converse also true?

Comment: regarding 2: isn't $k$ defined only $\mu$-a.e. ?

Comment: In regard to 2, how did you get your implication? Not at all implying it's false, on the contrary the proof of that usually consists in computing the adjoint of $K$ directly, so you would know following that proof that the other implication is true.

Comment: @BrunoB Okay, so it's all about the fact that the of two kernel define the same operator, they coincide a. e., which can be shown taking an indicator as $f$, right?

Comment: There is [the Schur test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_test) which can applied to $|k(x,y)|.$